# Help overwritting some model file and block of wishlist

Tags: overrides, wishlist

I'm trying to override some files of wishlist core module. This is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Srh_Wishlist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Srh_Wishlist>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Srh_Wishlist</module>
                    <frontName>wishlist</frontName>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <Srh_wishlist_indexcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/wishlist/index/#]]></from>
                <!-- Mage_Wishlist_IndexController  -->
                <to>/wishlist/index/</to>
                <!-- Srh_Wishlist_IndexController  -->
            </Srh_wishlist_indexcontroller>
        </rewrite>
        <blocks>
            <wishlist>
                <class>Srh_Wishlist_Model</class>
            </wishlist>
            <wishlist>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_wishlist>Srh_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist</customer_wishlist>
                </rewrite>
            </wishlist>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <wishlist>
                <class>Srh_Wishlist_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>wishlist_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </wishlist>
            <wishlist_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <item_collection>Srh_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection</item_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </wishlist_resource>
            <wishlist>
                <rewrite>
                    <item>Srh_Wishlist_Model_Item</item>
                </rewrite>
            </wishlist>
            <wishlist>
                <rewrite>
                    <wishlist>Srh_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist</wishlist>
                </rewrite>
            </wishlist>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <wishlist after="Mage_Adminhtml">Srh_Wishlist</wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Apparently it works fine, but in system.log I have next problem:

> Warning: include(Srh/Wishlist/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Srh/Wishlist/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

And in file exception.log:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Srh_Wishlist_Model_Links' in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:595

I don't want to override `Model/Observer.php` even `Model/Links.php` from Wishlist Magento module. Why Magento are throwing this errors? I have something wrong in my `config.xml`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need edit `config.xml` this below.

You can read more about Overriding Block, Models, Helper,Controller in http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
     <modules>
        <Srh_Wishlist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Srh_Wishlist>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
     <routers>
         <wishlist>
            <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Srh_Wishlist</module>
                    <frontName>wishlist</frontName>
                    <srh_wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Srh_Wishlist</srh_wishlist>
                </args>
        </wishlist>
    </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
       <blocks>
           <wishlist>
               <class>Srh_Wishlist_Block</class>
           </wishlist>
           <wishlist>
               <rewrite>        
                 <customer_wishlist>Srh_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist</customer_wishlist>
               </rewrite>
          </wishlist>
      </blocks>
      <models>
        <wishlist>
            <class>Srh_Wishlist_Model</class>
        </wishlist>
        <wishlist_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <item_collection>Srh_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection</item_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </wishlist_resource>
        <wishlist>
            <rewrite>
                <item>Srh_Wishlist_Model_Item</item>
            </rewrite>
        </wishlist>
        <wishlist>
            <rewrite>
                <wishlist>Srh_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist</wishlist>
            </rewrite>
        </wishlist>
     </models>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <wishlist after="Mage_Adminhtml">Srh_Wishlist_Adminhtml</wishlist>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different tag for your module's blocks, models, and helpers identifier since `<wishlist>` is already taken by Mage_Wishlist.

Best practice dictates you snake_case your module's namespace_modulename, so in your case, you should use `<srh_wishlist>`.

What's happening above is that you are declaring that the `<wishlist>` node should apply to your module, and thus Magento can't find the actual Mage_Wishlist blocks to use.